# Accessing Conda in non-graphical mode Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I want to use anaconda environments in non-graphical mode (Ctrl-Alt-F2) on Ubuntu 18.04. Everything works perfect in regular Ubuntu. However, in non-graphical mode command 'conda' is not found. For that matter I don't have either base or any of my environments available. I used to access conda in non-graphical by loading conda (module load anconda3) in the University, but now I want to use it on my personal desktop. Any ideas?

Comment: You can access non-graphical mode by using a terminal. You don't have to access a TTY screen. Is there a benefit to using TTY?

Comment: The problem with regular terminal is that OS consumes around 320 Mb of GPU memory, Whilst in non-graphical the GPU consumption is less than 50 Mb. My GPU is quite old and every MB counts.

Comment: Try to install [stterm](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/x11/stterm) it's a low usage terminal. [More info](https://st.suckless.org/). I use [this version](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/st) as my daily driver.

Comment: _However, in non-graphical mode command 'conda' is not found._ Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes. I am getting      
"conda: command not found"